# Play number of videos in VideoView from folder specified android

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

I have tried following code to display `VideoView` according to the number of videos present in specified folder. It isn't playing the videos and just show only single videoview. Any suggestions please.

**Code**

```
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Funtube/UserData/Videos/" + File.separator);
 File[] list = file.listFiles();
 for (File f: list){
  String name = f.getName();
  if (name.endsWith(".mp4"))
   count++;
    for(int a=0;a<=count;a++)
    {
     VideoView vdos=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
     String path=file.getAbsolutePath()+name;
      vdos.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
       vdos.start();
      }
```

Comment: use on completion listener than play next Video

Comment: But how to increment `VideoView`? As i have showed single `VideoView` in my activity. I want to display all the videos in different `VideoViews`

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onCreate()
{
       link=new LinkedList<String>();
         //declare linklist globally
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "Funtube/UserData/Videos/" + File.separator);
        File[] list = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : list) {
            String name = f.getName();
            if (name.endsWith(".mp4"))
            String path = file.getAbsolutePath() + name;
            //adding all Videos To List 
            link.add(path);
        }   


}

public void startvideo()
{
    VideoView vdos=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String path=link.get(0);
     vdos.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
      vdos.start();

}

vv.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        String video=link.get(0);
        link.remove(0);
        link.add(video);
        //this above code will put first video to last index of list 
        //by doing this we can play one video after another

        startvideo();
    }
});
```

you need to initilize LinkList in Oncreate also add oncomplet..
      Listener

Comment: Will this code increment number of `VideoView` in my activity file?

Comment: it will remove first index element and put to last ... now we have second on top ....